# Is the endpoint of a domain automatically an extreme point?

Tags: calculus, optimization, continuity

Consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \sin(1/x) &\mbox{if } x>0 \\ 0 &\mbox{if } x=0.\end{cases}$$

Does this function have a minimum at $f(0)$ ?  I did Google the question, and apparently there is no local minimum at that point. Why ? Assuming I define the domain to be $[0,2π]$, the point $x=0$ is an endpoint which should make it a minimum. Am I correct in my reasoning?

Thomas' calculus suggests that a function can have an extreme value at the following points:

1. Interior points where $f'(c) =0.$
2. Interior points where $f'(c)$ is undefined.
3. Endpoints of the domain of $f$.

Comment: No, the fact that $0$ is an endpoint does not make it a minimum (neither a maximum).

Comment: Maybe you should change your title to something like "Is an endpoint of the domain automatically a minimum?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a minimum for $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ at $x_0$ on $D$ we need

- For all $ x \in D: f(x_0) \le f(x)$

In your case $x_0 = 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. Alas for $x_0 = 2/(3\pi) \in [0,2\pi]$ we have $f(2/(3\pi)) = \sin(3 \pi / 2) = -1 < 0$, so $f(x_0)$ is no minimum.

[image: graph]

The graph above suggests that on every interval $I = [0, \epsilon)$, with $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_k = 1/(3\pi/2 + 2\pi k) \in I$ $(*)$ and at $x_k$ there is local minimum of $\sin(1/x)$ with $f(x_k) = -1$, which is less than $f(0) = 0$. So there is no local minimum of $f$ at $0$.

About $(*)$:
\begin{align}
x_k &< \epsilon \iff \\
3\pi/2 + 2\pi k &> 1 / \epsilon \iff \\
k &> (1/\epsilon - 3\pi/2) / (2\pi)
\end{align}

For any real $y \in \mathbb{R}$ there is a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n > y$, which is a consequence of the axiom of Archimedes.

Comment: For a local minimum (which I think the question is about) there should be a neighbourhood $N$ of $0$ with $f(0) < f(x)$ $\forall x \in N, x \neq 0$. Alas, for all $\epsilon > 0$ we can find $x \in (0,\epsilon)$ with $f(x) < f(0) = 0$, so there's no minimum.

Comment: Note that I'm interested in finding the local minima. Is it still not correct?

Comment: Folks, I misread $f$ for $1/\sin(x)$ first, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The full statement should be that for a piecewise differentiable function, *if the absolute extrema exists, then it is the point where one of the 3 conditions hold*. It is **NOT** true that if any of the condition holds, then the point is automatically an extrema.

Answer (score 0):

The function **could** have an extreme value in all the cases you listed, but **it is not certain**.

If some point $x_0$ in the domain falls in any of those cases, **you should test it** to see if it is a minimum, a maximum, or neither of those.

This test should make sure that there are no points arbitrarily close to $x_0$ where $f$ has values that exceed (in case of a maximum test) or are inferior to (in case of a minimum test)  the value $f(x_0)$.

In your case, it is neither, because the points $$\frac 1 {\frac\pi2 + \pi}, \frac 1 {\frac\pi2 + 2\pi}, \frac 1 {\frac\pi2 + 3\pi}, \dots$$ get arbitrarily close to $0$ and at those $f$ takes the values $$-1, 1, -1, \dots,$$ which are inferior to and exceed $f(0) = 0$ alternately.

A useful test for local minimum/maximum in the interior of a domain is [the second derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Second_derivative_test). See also the first derivative test in that same article. Similarly, if $f$ is continuous and differentiable and $f'$ is positive up to a left endpoint, then that endpoint is a minimum. However, none of these apply to your case.

If no test is applicable, you should use your own skills manipulating inequalities to try to show that some point is a local minimum or maximum, or maybe come up with a counterexample like the one I gave above.